# Как сделать обратный отчет до окончания музыки на swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, аудио, avfoundation

Делаю аудио приложение. Захотел сделать обратный отчет о окончания музыки для удобства юзера.

```
func playSound() {
    if isPlaying == false {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player.numberOfLoops = 0
            player.play()

            isPlaying = true

            detailView.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause-icon"), forState: .Normal)

            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Play music error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        isPlaying = false
        detailView.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play-icon"), forState: .Normal)
        player.pause()
    }
}
```

Попытка сделать функцию обновления времени, но не то:

```
func updateTime() {
    let currentTime = player.duration
    let minutes = Int((currentTime / 60.0)%60)
    let seconds = Int(currentTime % 60.0) - Int(player.currentTime)
    detailView.timeLabel.text = String(format: "- %02d мин. %02d сек.", minutes, seconds)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете заюзать мой класс. Реализовал там таймер. Можете из него также выдрать конкретный кусок для ваших нужд. А можете целиком его как сервис прикрутить:

```
import Foundation
```

class Timer {

```
static let instance = Timer()
private var timerArray = [String:TimerData]()

private class TimerData {
    var tickCount: Int
    let dispatch_timer:DispatchSourceTimer!
    let queue: DispatchQueue
    init(tickCount: Int, dispatch_timer: DispatchSourceTimer, queue: DispatchQueue) {
        self.tickCount = tickCount
        self.dispatch_timer = dispatch_timer
        self.queue = queue
    }
}

//MARK:- Main functions

class func startCountdown(key: String,
                          tickCount: Int!,
                          tickActionEvery: Int? = 1,
                          tickAction: (()->())? = nil,
                          completion: @escaping (()->())) {
    Timer.stopTimer(key: key)

    let q = DispatchQueue(label:"timer.queue:\(key)")
    let dispatch_timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags.init(rawValue: 0), queue:q)
    let timerData = TimerData(tickCount: tickCount, dispatch_timer: dispatch_timer, queue: q)
    Timer.instance.timerArray[key.uppercased()] = timerData

    q.async{
        let interval: Double = 1.0
        let delay = DispatchTime.now()
        var step = 1
        dispatch_timer.schedule(deadline: delay, repeating: interval, leeway: .nanoseconds(0))
        dispatch_timer.setEventHandler {

            if let tick = tickAction,
                let tickEvery = tickActionEvery {
                if step >= tickEvery {
                    step = 1
                    tick()
                }
                else {
                    step += 1
                }
            }

            timerData.tickCount -= 1
            if timerData.tickCount <= 0 {
                Timer.stopTimer(key: key)
                completion()

            }
        }
        dispatch_timer.resume()
    }
}

class func startTimer(key: String, tickAction: @escaping (()->())) {
    Timer.stopTimer(key: key)

    let q = DispatchQueue(label:"timer.queue:\(key)")
    let dispatch_timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags.init(rawValue: 0), queue:q)
    let timerData = TimerData(tickCount: 0, dispatch_timer: dispatch_timer, queue: q)
    Timer.instance.timerArray[key.uppercased()] = timerData

    q.async{
        let interval: Double = 1.0
        let delay = DispatchTime.now()
        dispatch_timer.schedule(deadline: delay, repeating: interval, leeway: .nanoseconds(0))
        dispatch_timer.setEventHandler {
            tickAction()
        }
        dispatch_timer.resume()
    }
}

class func stopTimer(key: String) {
    let timerData = Timer.instance.timerArray[key.uppercased()]
    timerData?.dispatch_timer.cancel()
    Timer.instance.timerArray[key.uppercased()] = nil
}

//MARK:- Service

class func tickCount(key: String) -> Int {
    guard let timerData = Timer.instance.timerArray[key] else {
        return 0
    }

    return timerData.tickCount
}

class func count() -> Int {
    return Timer.instance.timerArray.count
}
```

}

Вызов следующий. В вашем случае:
key - любое уникальное имя для таймера
tickCount - количество секунд
tickActionEvery - через какой промежуток отрабатывает tickAction
tickAction - собственно сам action где можно выводить в UI оставшееся время
ну и код по завершению таймера. Его можно грохать как вручную, но по завершению он сам отключается и удаляется из массива.

```
Timer.startCountdown(key: "CUSTOM_KEY_NAME", tickCount: 100, tickActionEvery: 1, tickAction: {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //UI output code
        }
    }) {
        // completion code
    }
```